# How to add a div element to the html view using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here I want to add some div to the view using javascript results.

I tried on page load hiding the div and then showing it through the javascirpt.

But there what happens is, first it shows the div content on the load and then hides from the javascript.

So I wonder, I will give a main div in the view as,

```
<div id = "ManagerSection">

</div>
```

and put my code into the div from the javascript.

So I tried this,

```
function myfunction() {

  document.getElementById("ManagerSection").innerHTML +=
  "<h3>This is the text which has been inserted by JS</h3>";

}
```

This will add the text, but in my scenario, I want to add this

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 order-1">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-6 mb-4">
       <div class="card">
         <div class="card-body">
           <div class="card-title d-flex align-items-start justify-content-between">
             <div class="avatar flex-shrink-0">
               <img src="~/Theme/assets/img/icons/unicons/chart-success.png" alt="chart success" class="rounded" />
             </div>
             <div class="dropdown">
               <button class="btn p-0" type="button" id="cardOpt3" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 <i class="bx bx-dots-vertical-rounded"></i>
               </button>
               <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="cardOpt3">
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">View More</a>
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete</a>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <span class="fw-semibold d-block mb-1">Pending Approvals</span>
           <h3 class="card-title mb-2">0</h3>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-6 mb-4">
       <div class="card">
         <div class="card-body">
           <div class="card-title d-flex align-items-start justify-content-between">
             <div class="avatar flex-shrink-0">
               <img src="~/Theme/assets/img/icons/unicons/chart-success.png" alt="chart success" class="rounded" />
             </div>
             <div class="dropdown">
               <button class="btn p-0" type="button" id="cardOpt3" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 <i class="bx bx-dots-vertical-rounded"></i>
               </button>
               <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="cardOpt3">
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">View More</a>
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete</a>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <span class="fw-semibold d-block mb-1">Pending Approvals</span>
           <h3 class="card-title mb-2">0</h3>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-4 order-3 order-md-2">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-6 mb-4">
       <div class="card">
         <div class="card-body">
           <div class="card-title d-flex align-items-start justify-content-between">
             <div class="avatar flex-shrink-0">
               <img src="~/Theme/assets/img/icons/unicons/cc-primary.png" alt="Credit Card" class="rounded" />
             </div>
             <div class="dropdown">
               <button class="btn p-0" type="button" id="cardOpt1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 <i class="bx bx-dots-vertical-rounded"></i>
               </button>
               <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="cardOpt1">
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">View More</a>
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete</a>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <span class="fw-semibold d-block mb-1">Outlets</span>
           <h3 class="card-title mb-2">0</h3>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-6 mb-4">
       <div class="card">
         <div class="card-body">
           <div class="card-title d-flex align-items-start justify-content-between">
             <div class="avatar flex-shrink-0">
               <img src="~/Theme/assets/img/icons/unicons/cc-primary.png" alt="Credit Card" class="rounded" />
             </div>
             <div class="dropdown">
               <button class="btn p-0" type="button" id="cardOpt1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 <i class="bx bx-dots-vertical-rounded"></i>
               </button>
               <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="cardOpt1">
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">View More</a>
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete</a>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <span class="fw-semibold d-block mb-1">Outlets</span>
           <h3 class="card-title mb-2">0</h3>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

When I copy this to the javascript within the ```double quotes``it copy as a c# code within the javascript.

Want to know how to do this?

Comment: C# code? What do you mean by that?

Comment: you have to excape first of all the double quotes within your code. single quotes vs double quotes, watch out there. I would preferly build a template and loop that part.

Comment: @CodeThing Sorry, I want to mean that within the javascript html code is pasted like normal c# code. not in the format as ``double quotation``

Comment: @Dorvalla changing all double quotes in to single, will do the work ??

Comment: Try using template literals instead of double quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try this method?? hope it works for you

```js
document.getElementById("ManagerSection").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend",`<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 order-1">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-6 mb-4">
       <div class="card">
         <div class="card-body">
           <div class="card-title d-flex align-items-start justify-content-between">
             <div class="avatar flex-shrink-0">
               <img src="~/Theme/assets/img/icons/unicons/chart-success.png" alt="chart success" class="rounded" />
             </div>
             <div class="dropdown">
               <button class="btn p-0" type="button" id="cardOpt3" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 <i class="bx bx-dots-vertical-rounded"></i>
               </button>
               <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="cardOpt3">
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">View More</a>
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete</a>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <span class="fw-semibold d-block mb-1">Pending Approvals</span>
           <h3 class="card-title mb-2">0</h3>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-6 mb-4">
       <div class="card">
         <div class="card-body">
           <div class="card-title d-flex align-items-start justify-content-between">
             <div class="avatar flex-shrink-0">
               <img src="~/Theme/assets/img/icons/unicons/chart-success.png" alt="chart success" class="rounded" />
             </div>
             <div class="dropdown">
               <button class="btn p-0" type="button" id="cardOpt3" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 <i class="bx bx-dots-vertical-rounded"></i>
               </button>
               <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="cardOpt3">
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">View More</a>
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete</a>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <span class="fw-semibold d-block mb-1">Pending Approvals</span>
           <h3 class="card-title mb-2">0</h3>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-4 order-3 order-md-2">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-6 mb-4">
       <div class="card">
         <div class="card-body">
           <div class="card-title d-flex align-items-start justify-content-between">
             <div class="avatar flex-shrink-0">
               <img src="~/Theme/assets/img/icons/unicons/cc-primary.png" alt="Credit Card" class="rounded" />
             </div>
             <div class="dropdown">
               <button class="btn p-0" type="button" id="cardOpt1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 <i class="bx bx-dots-vertical-rounded"></i>
               </button>
               <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="cardOpt1">
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">View More</a>
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete</a>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <span class="fw-semibold d-block mb-1">Outlets</span>
           <h3 class="card-title mb-2">0</h3>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-6 mb-4">
       <div class="card">
         <div class="card-body">
           <div class="card-title d-flex align-items-start justify-content-between">
             <div class="avatar flex-shrink-0">
               <img src="~/Theme/assets/img/icons/unicons/cc-primary.png" alt="Credit Card" class="rounded" />
             </div>
             <div class="dropdown">
               <button class="btn p-0" type="button" id="cardOpt1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 <i class="bx bx-dots-vertical-rounded"></i>
               </button>
               <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="cardOpt1">
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">View More</a>
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete</a>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <span class="fw-semibold d-block mb-1">Outlets</span>
           <h3 class="card-title mb-2">0</h3>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>`)
```

```html
<div id="ManagerSection"></div>
```